# Android can I Make App controll Android System

Tags: android

I want to create App that Make My Device with multi-Users "username and password for every user"
Users can share the Device , every user can open different Apps "Ex. Camera , Contacts" and prevent from another app

the App must run at system Start up    request your username and password  and then

the App will Make You Run Some App and Prevent you from some App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly this isn't possible with the stock Android ROMS - security like that has to be implemented by the operating system and no app has that level of control.

Also, if you don't know that this isn't possible, you are unlikely to have the knowledge to implement the other things an operating system has to do like memory/disk management, security, etc...

If you *really* want to try, you need to get hold of an Android ROM and start modifying it. This will require low-level understanding of the hardware, processor, etc... and would require rooting the target device

Answer (score 0):

No.

This would require a drastically modified custom build of android, it's not something that can be done (except in the most crude and easily circumvented way) using an app.